# How to MergeSort a String ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting

so i've been trying to figure out this code for the past couple of days now and im getting nowhere. This is the furthest i've got, but now it's not displaying the final sorted array, and any code i try and add past the return merged statement is apparently unereachable :/

```
import java.util.*;

public class MergeTestStringArray
{


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList< String > array = new ArrayList< String >();

    array.add("John");
    array.add("Victor");
    array.add("Joe");
    array.add("Jackson");
    array.add("Anthony");
    array.add("Angelina");
    array.add("George");
    array.add("Paul");

    ArrayList< String > sortedArray = new ArrayList< String >();

    sortedArray = mergeSort(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(" " + sortedArray.get(i) );
    }
  }

  public static ArrayList< String > mergeSort(ArrayList< String > list)
  {
    ArrayList < String > sorted = new ArrayList< String >();
    if (list.size() == 1)
    {
        sorted = list;
    } else {
        int mid1 = list.size() /2;

        ArrayList< String > left = new ArrayList< String >();
        ArrayList< String > right = new ArrayList< String >();

        for ( int x = 0; x < mid1; x++) {
            left.add(list.get(x));

        }
        for ( int x = mid1; x < list.size(); x++) {
            right.add(list.get(x));
        }

        System.out.println("Left Array: " + left);
        System.out.println("Right Array)" + right);

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        mergeArray(left,right);
    }

    return sorted;
  }

private static ArrayList< String > mergeArray(ArrayList< String > left, ArrayList< String > right)
{
    ArrayList< String > merged = new ArrayList< String >();

    int i = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int r = 0;

    while (l < left.size() && r < right.size())
           {
              if ((left.get(l)).compareTo(right.get(r)) < 0)
              {
                 merged.add(left.get(l));
                 l++;
              }
              else
              {
                 merged.add(right.get(r));
                 r++;
              }

              i++;
           }


           while (l < left.size())
           {
              merged.add(left.get(l));
              l++;
              i++;
           }

           // Append rest of the values in the right half, if any...
           while (r < right.size())
           {
              merged.add(right.get(r));
              r++;
                  i++;
           }

    return merged;


  }

}
```

Comment: If this is homework, you should use the homework tag.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your question is but.. statements after return statements are generally unreachable. Once the function reaches the return statement it will exist the function and return the value at that return statement..

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in your mergeSort function.  Specifically, in your recursive case, you never actually save the result of the sort to the `merged` list.  Try replacing

```
mergeArray(left,right);
```

with

```
sorted = mergeArray(left,right);
```

Comment: Okay that works, except the sorting isnt perfect, it sorted the array to: 

Anthony
Angelina
George
John
Paul
Victor
Joe
Jackson

Nearly there, but not quite, what else should i implement to perfectly sort it?

Answer (score 0):

assign the return value of `mergeArray` to `sorted`.

```
sorted = mergeArray(left,right);
```

And assign the results of your mergeSort calls:

```
        left = mergeSort(left);
        right = mergeSort(right);
```

Also, you do not need to create an empty ArrayList to declare a variable, when you are not going to use it.

The following will suffice:

```
ArrayList < String > sorted;
```

Comment: Thankyou, however, it's still not sorting properly :/ any ideas as to why? The current output is: Anthony
Angelina
George
John
Paul
Victor
Joe
Jackson

Comment: @amartin94 there is a good reason for that, see the edited answer. the results of your function were not being assigned correctly. Is this a howework?

Comment: No, just trying to grow a better understanding of how mergeSort works - I will be using some sort of sort for an assignment down the track, but at the moment im trying to gain a better understanding of how a mergeSort works

Comment: @amartin94 fair enough. Do you understand why the result of the 2 mergeSort() calls needs to be assigned back to left & right?

Comment: Not really :/ The whole mergeSort concept has been difficult for me.. but thanks for the help ::D

Comment: @amartin94 Did the fix work? Think of the sort this way: 1. divide into n sublists 2. repeatedly merge the sublists. Each of the mergeSort calls returns a sorted sublist, so the merge function should be merging these sorted sublists.